# Arbitrary number of type parameters in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I need to pass a List of Types to a method, but I want to be sure (at compile time that is) that all of them inherit from BaseType.
Also, I dont know how many Types have to be passed.

So I figured this would be a bad way to go:

```
public void DoSomething(params Type[] types)
```

So what I ended up doing up to now is something like this:

```
private void DoSomething(params Type[] types)

public void DoSomething<T1>() 
    where T1 : BaseType
{ 
    DoSomething(typeof(T1)); 
}

public void DoSomething<T1, T2>() 
    where T1 : BaseType
    where T2 : BaseType
{ 
    DoSomething(typeof(T1), typeof(T2)); 
}


public void DoSomething<T1, T2, T3>() 
    where T1 : BaseType
    where T2 : BaseType
    where T3 : BaseType{...}

// and so on...
```

You get the Idea.
So the Question is: **can you do this a bit more beautifully?**
Because this does not support an arbitrary number of types.
And in my scenario, eight or more types would not be too uncommon.

I want to use this for "magic" of [this](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2008/09/resolving-arrays-with-windsor.html) kind but the caller does not have a reference to the container.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no way to represent such a constraint in C# (or CIL for that matter), so you're going to either have to struggle through with writing all those overloads, or give up compile-time safety and just check at run-time.

If possible, one other alternative would be to write an overload that can make use of examples. Whether or not this would be useful depends on the domain, really.

```
public void DoSomething(params BaseClass[] examples)
{
    //null-checks here

   Type[] types = examples.Select(e => e.GetType())
                          .ToArray();
   //...    
}
```

Usage (let's say the `BaseClass` was `Mammal`):

```
// Compiles fine.
DoSomething(new Goat(), new Tiger(), new Lion());

// Won't compile.
DoSomething(new Fish(), new Tiger(), new Lion());
```

And here's a sample for checking at run-time:

```
public void DoSomething(Type[] types)
{
    //null-checks here

    // Or perhaps you want IsSubclassOf...
   if(types.Any(t => !typeof(BaseClass).IsAssignableFrom(t))
        throw new ArgumentException(...);           
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, a generic type is defined by the namespace, the class name, and the number of type parameters (i.e. you can't have a class with the same name in the same namespace with the same number of type parameters, even if the constraints on them are different).

If it was possible to have a single class have an undefined number of type parameters, then the framework would have taken advantage of this with the Action<> and Func<> classes, which it doesn't.