# How can i create an interface in C# that has an arbitrary number of generic parameters ?

Tags: c#, generics, unity-game-engine, parameters, interface

So recently I have stumbled upon a youtube video(I'm not sure i can link it) about efficiency in c#, mainly writing efficient code for a unity engine game. So at some point in the video he showcases a struct that implements an interface with arbitrary number of generic parameters. Here is a picture to illustrate what he did:

[image]

The interface I am trying to replicate is the IJobsProcess. So what I got from what he said in the video is that the interface can take an arbitrary number of generic parameters. In conclusion how can i create an interface like that in c#?
And please correct me if I said anything wrong here.

Comment: I don't think you understood correctly, there is no way to have an arbitrary amount of generic parameters. The interface in the picture has 2 generic type parameters

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but you can use a [`params object[] args`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params) argument in C# to allow `0-many` object arguments passed to a method.

Comment: Could you paste link to video, just curious..

Comment: Here is the link to the video at 56:11"https://youtu.be/tGmnZdY5Y-E?t=56m11s" around this time he showcases the above implementation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write and implement interface with any amount of [generic parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-type-parameters). But you **cannot** write interfaces with arbitrary amount of generic parameters.

Here is example for you:

```
interface IService<T1, T2>
{
    T1 GetValue();
    T2 GetAnotherValue();
}
class MyClass : IService<string, int>
{
    public int GetAnotherValue()
    {
        return 42;
    }

    public string GetValue()
    {
        return "Truth";
    }
}
```

As you see above, number of generic parameters can be more than 1, but that number is fixed in compile-time.

Same question is asked also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343383/arbitrary-number-of-type-parameters-in-c-sharp) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612887/can-i-have-a-variable-number-of-generic-parameters). In those questions there are mentioned few alternatives, where arbitrary amount of Type-parameters are implemented with other common known C#-features: with [params](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params) keyword or passing [array of types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1612903/5789864) as parameter.

Comment: I see your point, nonetheless if i may here is a link to the video "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tGmnZdY5Y-E" at 55:46 he implements the above mentioned code, could i get some insight on what he is doing there, from your point of view ? I got a little confused there and still am.

Comment: In the video guy showed just normal good-old-generic type (with 2 generic arguments). Basically it was same case as my example. In my example there is IService interface which takes T1 and T2, and MyClass implements IService with T1=string and T2=int. In video, implementation class was GravityMinionJob, which implemented IJobProcessComponentData with generic types T1=MinionVelocity and T2=RotationSpeed. I think you can now mark this question answered.

Comment: So bottom line is, he just has multiple implementations of the generic interface like say MyInterface<T1> or MyInterface<T1,T2> or Myinterface<T1,T2,T3> etc. i presume?

Comment: Yes, he has multiple separate interfaces which has different amount of generic parameters.

Comment: Thank you for clearing this up for me! Have a nice day mister!

Comment: Thanks! Happy hacking times to you! 

Comment: A good example is the Action Func classes. I think they have like 9 different versions from no parameter to 8 parameters.http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/action.cs,486d58da4553e12d so no param style case for generic. That's what makes them strongly typed. It is explicitely open but at compile time, the type is clearly defined.